# QT Visual studio tools always creates x86 Qt project

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I have Qt Creator project. Every time I open the pro file from Qt VS tools, I only get x86 project. In Qt options, I have two compilers, x86 and x64 compiler (default). Even using x64 default compiler produces x86 project.

My project pro file looks like this.

```
TEMPLATE = app

TARGET = myApp

QT += qml quick core

CONFIG += c++11

HEADERS += main.h 

SOURCES += main.cpp 

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

# Default rules for deployment.
include(deployment.pri)
INCLUDEPATH += include \
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Include\10.0.17134.0\um\windows.h\

MAKE_SPEC = $$split(QMAKESPEC, /)
contains(MAKE_SPEC, msvc2017_64):{
  LIBS += -L"$$PWD/lib/x64" -lftd2xx
} else {
  LIBS += -L"$$PWD/lib/x86" -lftd2xx
}

DISTFILES += deployment.pri \
    lib/ftd2xx.lib \
    ui/main.qml 

SUBDIRS += myapp.pro

DESTDIR = bin
```

Comment: Just for debugging, have you tried `LIBS += -L"$$PWD/lib/x64" -lftd2xx` only?, maybe it enters always in the else.

Comment: Yes, trying that also produces only x86 project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The platform is selected according to the current default Qt version (Qt VS Tools > Options > Default Qt/Win version). If an x64 Qt build is selected, new projects will be configured with the x64 platform.